# Qual o comando que está sendo usado de forma errada nesse script?

Tags: shell-script

Sempre quando rodo o script, aparece a mensagem de erro dizendo que o `grep` foi usado de forma errada, o que tem de errado no script ?

Código:

```
#!/bin/bash

read $ALVO
RESULTADO=$(ps -A | grep $ALVO)
$RESULTADO kill -KILL
```

Mensagem de erro:

```
sublime
Uso: grep [OPÇÃO]... PADRÃO [ARQUIVO]...
Experimente "grep --help" para mais informações.
kill: uso: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... ou kill -l [sigspec]
```

Obs: Aqui o sublime foi um teste

Answer (score 1):

Como ainda não foi atribuído um valor a variável `ALVO` você não pode referenciá-la com "$". Como a variável está vazia ao utilizá-la com o comando `grep` é retornado um erro.

```
#!/bin/bash
read ALVO
RESULTADO=$(ps -A | grep $ALVO)
$RESULTADO kill -KILL
```